# Saving and re-opening data in text boxes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm in my final year of school, year 12, and I'm trying to make a weekly planner program that my client is able to open, input their data into the allocated text boxes and then click a "save" button and close the window, and when they re-open the window, their previously entered data will already be there. I have already created my window, headings, text box grid, and a "clear" button which clears all the data inside the text boxes. I have created the "save" button but there is no command linked to it.
Here is my code: (it's pretty long and most of it is probably unnecessary but it does what I want):

```
from tkinter import Scale,Tk,Frame,Label,Button
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook,Entry,Button

root = Tk()
#title of the window
root.title('Orgnaiser')
#how big the window is in pixels
root.geometry("1700x700")


#program sets up a range of rows and columns:
for row in range(21):
    for column in range(7):#program then checks for the required info of row and column number
        if row==0 and column==0:#if these numbers match:
            label = Label(root, text="Monday")#the heading text of the first column will be "Monday",
            label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))#the font of the heading will be "comic sans ms"
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
            root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        if row==0 and column==1:#repeats the same process as before but changes the heading text to "Tuesday",
            label = Label(root, text="Tuesday")# and moves it a column over to the right
            label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
            root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        if row==0 and column==2:#repeats the same process as before but changes the heading text to "Wednesday",
            label = Label(root, text="Wednesday")# and moves it a column over to the right
            label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
            root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        if row==0 and column==3:#repeats the same process as before but changes the heading text to "Thursday",
            label = Label(root, text="Thursday")# and moves it a column over to the right
            label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
            root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        if row==0 and column==4:#repeats the same process as before but changes the heading text to "Friday",
            label = Label(root, text="Friday")# and moves it a column over to the right
            label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
            root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        if row==0 and column==5:#repeats the same process as before but changes the heading text to "Saturday",
            label = Label(root, text="Saturday")# and moves it a column over to the right
            label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
            root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        if row==0 and column==6:#repeats the same process as before but changes the heading text to "Sunday",
            label = Label(root, text="Sunday")# and moves it a column over to the right
            label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
            root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
            
#The next process is to name the textboxes and sort out their positions
##This is very repetative task with the only diference between each of them is their name and position,
##grouped together within each day of the week.
        if row==1 and column==0:#text box is placed in specified spot in the grid
            a = Entry(root, text="")
            a.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==2 and column==0:##this same process is repeated for each specified grid space
            aa = Entry(root, text="")
            aa.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==3 and column==0:
            ab = Entry(root, text="")##tell the program that the text box can be edited/typed in
            ab.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==4 and column==0:
            ac = Entry(root, text="")
            ac.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)##confirms the placement and arrangement
                                                    ###of the textbox in the grid

        if row==5 and column==0:
            ad = Entry(root, text="")
            ad.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==6 and column==0:
            ae = Entry(root, text="")
            ae.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==7 and column==0:
            af = Entry(root, text="")
            af.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==8 and column==0:
            ag = Entry(root, text="")
            ag.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==9 and column==0:
            ah = Entry(root, text="")
            ah.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==10 and column==0:
            ai = Entry(root, text="")
            ai.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        
        


#Tuesday textboxes
##Process repeats as before

        if row==1 and column==1:
            b = Entry(root, text="")
            b.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==2 and column==1:
            ba = Entry(root, text="")
            ba.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==3 and column==1:
            bb = Entry(root, text="")
            bb.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==4 and column==1:
            bc = Entry(root, text="")
            bc.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==5 and column==1:
            bd = Entry(root, text="")
            bd.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==6 and column==1:
            be = Entry(root, text="")
            be.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==7 and column==1:
            bf = Entry(root, text="")
            bf.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==8 and column==1:
            bg = Entry(root, text="")
            bg.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==9 and column==1:
            bh = Entry(root, text="")
            bh.grid(row=9, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==10 and column==1:
            bi = Entry(root, text="")
            bi.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        
        
            
        
        
#Wednesday textboxes
#Process repeats as before
        
        if row==1 and column==2:
            c = Entry(root, text="")
            c.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==2 and column==2:
            ca = Entry(root, text="")
            ca.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==3 and column==2:
            cb = Entry(root, text="")
            cb.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==4 and column==2:
            cc = Entry(root, text="")
            cc.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==5 and column==2:
            cd = Entry(root, text="")
            cd.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==6 and column==2:
            ce = Entry(root, text="")
            ce.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==7 and column==2:
            cf = Entry(root, text="")
            cf.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==8 and column==2:
            cg = Entry(root, text="")
            cg.grid(row=8, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==9 and column==2:
            ch = Entry(root, text="")
            ch.grid(row=9, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==10 and column==2:
            ci = Entry(root, text="")
            ci.grid(row=10, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        
        
        
        
        
#Thursday textboxes
#Process repeats as before
        
        if row==1 and column==3:
            d = Entry(root, text="")
            d.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==2 and column==3:
            da = Entry(root, text="")
            da.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==3 and column==3:
            db = Entry(root, text="")
            db.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==4 and column==3:
            dc = Entry(root, text="")
            dc.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==5 and column==3:
            dd = Entry(root, text="")
            dd.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==6 and column==3:
            de = Entry(root, text="")
            de.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==7 and column==3:
            df = Entry(root, text="")
            df.grid(row=7, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==8 and column==3:
            dg = Entry(root, text="")
            dg.grid(row=8, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==9 and column==3:
            dh = Entry(root, text="")
            dh.grid(row=9, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==10 and column==3:
            di = Entry(root, text="")
            di.grid(row=10, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        
        
        
            
            
#Friday textboxes
#Process repeats as before
        
        if row==1 and column==4:
            e = Entry(root, text="")
            e.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==2 and column==4:
            ea = Entry(root, text="")
            ea.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==3 and column==4:
            eb = Entry(root, text="")
            eb.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==4 and column==4:
            ec = Entry(root, text="")
            ec.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==5 and column==4:
            ed = Entry(root, text="")
            ed.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==6 and column==4:
            ee = Entry(root, text="")
            ee.grid(row=6, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==7 and column==4:
            ef = Entry(root, text="")
            ef.grid(row=7, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==8 and column==4:
            eg = Entry(root, text="")
            eg.grid(row=8, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==9 and column==4:
            eh = Entry(root, text="")
            eh.grid(row=9, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==10 and column==4:
            ei = Entry(root, text="")
            ei.grid(row=10, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

        
        
        
            
            
#Saturday textboxes
#Process repeats as before
        
        if row==1 and column==5:
            f = Entry(root, text="")
            f.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==2 and column==5:
            fa = Entry(root, text="")
            fa.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==3 and column==5:
            fb = Entry(root, text="")
            fb.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==4 and column==5:
            fc = Entry(root, text="")
            fc.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==5 and column==5:
            fd = Entry(root, text="")
            fd.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==6 and column==5:
            fe = Entry(root, text="")
            fe.grid(row=6, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==7 and column==5:
            ff = Entry(root, text="")
            ff.grid(row=7, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==8 and column==5:
            fg = Entry(root, text="")
            fg.grid(row=8, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==9 and column==5:
            fh = Entry(root, text="")
            fh.grid(row=9, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==10 and column==5:
            fi = Entry(root, text="")
            fi.grid(row=10, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

        
        
        
        
#Sunday textboxes
#Process repeats as before
        
        if row==1 and column==6:
            g = Entry(root, text="")
            g.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==2 and column==6:
            ga = Entry(root, text="")
            ga.grid(row=2, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==3 and column==6:
            gb = Entry(root, text="")
            gb.grid(row=3, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==4 and column==6:
            gc = Entry(root, text="")
            gc.grid(row=4, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==5 and column==6:
            gd = Entry(root, text="")
            gd.grid(row=5, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==6 and column==6:
            ge = Entry(root, text="")
            ge.grid(row=6, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==7 and column==6:
            gf = Entry(root, text="")
            gf.grid(row=7, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

        if row==8 and column==6:
            gg = Entry(root, text="")
            gg.grid(row=8, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==9 and column==6:
            gh = Entry(root, text="")
            gh.grid(row=9, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
            
        if row==10 and column==6:
            gi = Entry(root, text="")
            gi.grid(row=10, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

        
            

#This is the "Clear" button, to clear all the inputs that the user enters into all the textboxes

def clearTextInput():
    a.delete("0", "end")
    aa.delete("0", "end")
    ab.delete("0", "end")
    ac.delete("0", "end")
    ad.delete("0", "end")
    ae.delete("0", "end")
    af.delete("0", "end")
    ag.delete("0", "end")
    ah.delete("0", "end")
    ai.delete("0", "end")

    
    b.delete("0", "end")
    ba.delete("0", "end")
    bb.delete("0", "end")
    bc.delete("0", "end")
    bd.delete("0", "end")
    be.delete("0", "end")
    bf.delete("0", "end")
    bg.delete("0", "end")
    bh.delete("0", "end")
    bi.delete("0", "end")

    
    c.delete("0", "end")
    ca.delete("0", "end")
    cb.delete("0", "end")
    cc.delete("0", "end")
    cd.delete("0", "end")
    ce.delete("0", "end")
    cf.delete("0", "end")
    cg.delete("0", "end")
    ch.delete("0", "end")
    ci.delete("0", "end")

    
    d.delete("0", "end")
    da.delete("0", "end")
    db.delete("0", "end")
    dc.delete("0", "end")
    dd.delete("0", "end")
    de.delete("0", "end")
    df.delete("0", "end")
    dg.delete("0", "end")
    dh.delete("0", "end")
    di.delete("0", "end")

    
    e.delete("0", "end")
    ea.delete("0", "end")
    eb.delete("0", "end")
    ec.delete("0", "end")
    ed.delete("0", "end")
    ee.delete("0", "end")
    ef.delete("0", "end")
    eg.delete("0", "end")
    eh.delete("0", "end")
    ei.delete("0", "end")

    
    f.delete("0", "end")
    fa.delete("0", "end")
    fb.delete("0", "end")
    fc.delete("0", "end")
    fd.delete("0", "end")
    fe.delete("0", "end")
    ff.delete("0", "end")
    fg.delete("0", "end")
    fh.delete("0", "end")
    fi.delete("0", "end")

    
    g.delete("0", "end")
    ga.delete("0", "end")
    gb.delete("0", "end")
    gc.delete("0", "end")
    gd.delete("0", "end")
    ge.delete("0", "end")
    gf.delete("0", "end")
    gg.delete("0", "end")
    gh.delete("0", "end")
    gi.delete("0", "end")


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
##'Save' button is yet to be programmed but will keep the inputed data saved to the textboxes,
## even if the window is closed and re-opened 
save_button = Button(root, text ="Save")
save_button.grid(row=19, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#A 'Clear' button, once activated, will clear all the text boxes in the window
clear_button = Button(root, text ="Clear", command=clearTextInput)
clear_button.grid(row=19, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)#Where within the grid the button is placed


root.mainloop()
```

I'm kinda new to coding and it's the only thing I need to complete my code. I would greatly appreciate anyone who can help me out with this because i have been stuck on this for a while.
Thank you.

Comment: You will have to save the data to an external file. For your needs, you can consider anything out of Plain Text Files (not recommended for confidential data), Shelve (allows saving data in data structures in a nice dictionary format (quite good for common needs)), sqlite3 (a lightweight version of MySQL and perfect for standalone desktop apps). Now, for more assistance on how to save the data, try reducing your code to a [Minimal Repoducible Example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your planner script, two things:

- Create a list of entry objects for the grid. This is a lot cleaner (and smaller) than separate variables.
- With the entry list, iterate through the entries to save\read the values to a csv file

Try this code:

```
from tkinter import Scale,Tk,Frame,Label,Button
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook,Entry,Button

root = Tk()
#title of the window
root.title('Organiser')
#how big the window is in pixels
root.geometry("1700x700")

# create label for each day
daylist = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
for i,dy in enumerate(daylist):
    label = Label(root, text=dy)#the heading text of the first column will be "Monday",
    label.config(font=('comic sans ms', 16))#the font of the heading will be "comic sans ms"
    label.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="nsew")
    root.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

entrylist = []  # list of all entry objects
for c in range(7):  # each column
   entrylist.append([])  # inner list for each row
   for r in range(10):  # each row
       a = Entry(root, text="")  # create entry object
       a.grid(row=r+1, column=c, padx=5, pady=5)
       entrylist[c].append(a)  # add to list

def clearTextInput():  # clear all entry boxes
    for c in entrylist:
        for r in c:
           r.delete("0", "end")

def save():
    import csv
    with open('plan.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for r in range(10):
           lst = []  # create list for each row of data
           for c in range(7):  # each column
              lst.append(entrylist[c][r].get())
           wr.writerow(lst)  # write row to csv
    
def load():
    clearTextInput()  # prevent mixed text
    import csv
    with open('plan.csv') as f:  # read csv file
        rd = csv.reader(f)
        for r,data in enumerate(rd): # read single row (list)
           for c in range(7):  # each column
              entrylist[c][r].insert(0, data[c])  # fill in text box
   

load_button = Button(root, text ="Load", command=load)
load_button.grid(row=19, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
   
save_button = Button(root, text ="Save", command=save)
save_button.grid(row=19, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

clear_button = Button(root, text ="Clear", command=clearTextInput)
clear_button.grid(row=19, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```